# arrays into function inside foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a function that I've been using to set the class in a div in html. Until now I just loaded the function on page load and then ran the variables through it each time the div is called.

```
function setclass($flow, $low, $good) { 
  if ($flow <= $low) 
    return "tdy"; 

  if ($flow <= $good) 
    return "tdg"; 

  return "tdr"; 
}
```

I just hardcode  the $low and $good as needed.

```
$low = (300); 
$good =(450);
$class = (setclass($flow[1], $low, $good));
```

And so on and on and on. As you can imagine I have some rather long scripts that could probably be done in 30 or 40 lines.

**edited **

The goal is a color coded css  table. Anything below the second column is yellow. In between the 2nd and 3rd green. Above the 3rd red. 
 Perhaps this is my own distorted logic and there is a simple and common solution.

I want to put a function inside a loop and run an array through it. 
I have a series of thresholds I want to loop through a function. the first column is a seperate array - flows 
the second is the low threshold. the third the high threshold

In the function anything below low returns tdy. Less than the third column returns tdg greater than returns tdr
    
    `$flows low good
    $flows[1] 1 3
    $flows[2] 2 4
    $flows[3] 3 5
    $flows[4] 4 6
    ...`

for example:

```
    $flows[1] => 2
    $flows[2] => 1
    $flows[3] => 6
    $flows[4] => 5
```

I want to loop those numbers through the function

and hopefully the result would be an array:

```
    [1] tdg
    [2] tdy
    [3] tdr
    [4] tdg
```

Comment: In the last piece of code, what's `$riv` and `$flo`?

Comment: those are two other arrays that part I can handle. `$riv = array('west fork', 'jarbidge', 'bruneau', 'owyhee');` and `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => PDT 52 P [1] => PDT [2] => 52 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => PDT 9.5 P [1] => PDT [2] => 9.5 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => MDT 191 P [1] => MDT [2] => 191 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => MDT 620 P [1] => MDT [2] => 620 ) )` Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I know they're arrays, but what's inside of them?

Comment: whoops didn't mean to hit return.

Comment: What exactly is the question. You're not clear on what you want to do.

Comment: I want to take all the hardcoded thresholds - low & good. In this case there are four sets. One for each riv.  and loop them through the function. I want a result is in an array that I can then loop through with the other arrays. The first result would look like: `westfork 52 tdy` And so on. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I could n't understand your problem completely. But You have mentioned $class is an array. $class store the result of setclass function right?  But in this function you did not return any array.. Have you cleared?

Comment: @grantiago Please improve your question to include all necessary input data and your attempt to code a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're after; just run the function for each loop iteration:

```
foreach ($flo as $i => $flo_item) {
    $class = setclass($flo_item[2], $low, $good);
    // use $riv[$i] and $class here
}
```

Comment: thanks. does that take into account that each element in riv will have a separate threshold in setclass?   `west fork  $low = (300); $good =(450);
bruneau $low = (450); $good =(3500);
jarbidge  $low = (60); $good =(450);
owyhee   $low = (900); $good =(10000);`

Comment: @grantiago You will have to update your question to make this requirement clearer; as of now I have no clue what `$riv` is any more.

Comment: thanks. I edited the original question. Hopefully it makes more sense.